# Programmatically add UILabel to toolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel, uitoolbar

I am trying to add a `UILabel` programmatically into my `UIToolBar` but it dose not seem to be appearing. This is what I am doing with my code.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    // Create custom toolbar at top of screen under navigation controller
    [matchingSeriesInfoToolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 30)];  
    matchingSeriesInfoToolBar = [UIToolbar new];
    [matchingSeriesInfoToolBar sizeToFit];
    CGFloat toolbarHeight = 30;
    CGRect mainViewBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    [matchingSeriesInfoToolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(mainViewBounds), 0, CGRectGetWidth(mainViewBounds), toolbarHeight)];
    matchingSeriesInfoToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:matchingSeriesInfoToolBar];

    // Create size of uitableview (to fit toolbar.
    [matchingSeriesTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30)];
    [self.view addSubview:matchingSeriesTableView];

    // Ad UILabel to the toolbar
    UIBarButtonItem *textFieldItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:manufSelectionLabel];
    matchingSeriesInfoToolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:textFieldItem];
    manufSelectionLabel.text = @"Hello World!";

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

So pretty much I have created a custom toolbar which I have changed the usual location from the bottom of the screen, to appear under the `UINavigationController`, this is also added to the view like this so it animated properly in the view transitions..

After which I create the size of the tableview so that it appears after the custom toolbar..

then from there I am trying to add a `UILabel` to the toolbar.. but for some reason its not working out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI: This code should be in `viewDidLoad` or every single time your view appears (which might include pressing the back button on another view!) you will get another toolbar etc :)

Comment: OH yes!!! sorry I had previously been working on a navigation toolbar animation so had tried to work in this.. but I never took the code from there.. I am so deep in trying to get this toolbar going i didnt see that. thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must actually create the label somewhere. This code works just fine.

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label];
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:item];

label.text = @"Hello World";
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly with my current toolbar.. I just skipped the first two lines then changed toolbar to mytoolbarname on the second to last line and it worked perfectly.. thank you very much.

Comment: If there is button on the tool bar , the label eats up the button.

Comment: @Shailesh I'm not sure what you mean by "eats up the button". If you have added a button in IB then you'll need to make sure the button is still in the toolbar.items array. If the label is covering the button, you'll need to make sure it's sized and positioned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted you don't ever make a `UILabel`. Your comment says *Ad UILabel to the toolbar* but you then proceed to make a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view `manufSectionLabel`.

Where is the code which creates `manufSectionLabel`?

---

PS This line does nothing :

```
[matchingSeriesInfoToolBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 30)];
```

because at that point matchingSeriesInfoToolbar is `nil` - you haven't made it yet!

Comment: opps matchingSeriesInfoToolBar should have been deleted it was part of my old code I was mucking around but when i was getting this question ready I just left it in. As for the first part of your quesiton, I am setting the getter and setters in the header file for the uilable.. should I then be calling ** manufSelectionLabel.text = @"Hello World!";** before I try to add the label to the uibarbutton thingy?

Comment: my concept of adding subviews etc is really lacking.. do you have any suggested tutorials, reading material that I could get ahold of to help beef up that part of my code.

Comment: Having a getter and setter does not actually create and configure the label. You have to allocate it somewhere. If you DO create the label in your getter, then you MUST use the getter instead of accessing the ivar directly (i.e. self.manufSectionLabel).